# time out for InetSocketAddress

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
```

The problem is that when the DNS is not accessible the InetSocketAddress takes 45sec to timeout and return an exception ("Host in not accessible...").
I need the entire command (so the creation of InetSocketAddress and the connect to timeout earlier. I did not find a way to make the `new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort)` timing out earlier.

Is it possible?

PS
I'm on Android but the problem is the same on other platform

Comment: Start a watchdog thread and `interrupt` after the required time?

Comment: Is that the only solution?

Comment: Alternatively use IP addresses I guess.

Comment: it's just that I don't understand why the timeout is not configurable since it is already there. But maybe that is not a real timeout. The operation takes a while to realize that the DNS is not accessible

Comment: and I can't use the ip address. The user needs to be able to define the address

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way. You need to run this code

```
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverHost, serverPort), CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
```

in a separate thread (i/o thread) and communicate with it from UI main thread. Once you are over your time limit - send it a terminate signal and proceeding in UI thread immediately, don't wait till it does terminate. Depending on the state, the i/o thread either dies immediately or eventually.